# Would it be realistically possible for an Earth-like planet to have a "hidden" moon?

Tags: science-based, planets, astronomy

I essentially just want the moon to always be in shadow of its planet so that from the surface of the planet it cannot be seen at any time of day - might "appear" as a black orb that blocks the light from distant stars at night - but I don't think that's possible as it does have to eventually orbit around to the sun/star-facing side of the planet.
Am I wrong about this? Is there some way for this to be possible?

Comment: Please note that when our very big Moon is in the shadow of the Earth it is clearly visible; the Earth has this thing called atmosphere which refracts more than enough sunlight to make the Moon plainly visible during eclipses -- dimmer than normal, and with a remarkable reddish color, but undoubtely visible. [This is how it looks like](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2007-03-03_-_Lunar_Eclipse_small-43img.gif#/media/File:2007-03-03_-_Lunar_Eclipse_small-43img.gif) (link to Wikimedia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Absolutely not. The only place that would qualify would be the L2 LaGrange points, and that's too far away to be totally in shadow.

I actually had a group of friends that thought that the phases of the Moon happened because it was in Earth's shadow, and I really had to blame the school system for such wide-spread misinformation.

I had another thought. L1 would also not be stable, but it would be harder to see. When the race develops telescopes, it would be smaller than a sun spot.

Comment: *And* it's dynamically unstable; you can *put* a moon there for a while, but it won't form naturally, and it won't stay for very long.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, planet and its moon must orbit around each other, so the moon can not always stay in the shade. There is L2 Lagrange point which is always in the shade (that's where James Webb space telescope is), but this is not a stable location, and natural satellite can not keep in it.

But if you are looking for preindustrial civilization which knows nothing about this moon, you may be in luck. If your planet is tidally locked with your moon, and your civilization is located on a continent opposite of that moon, its inhabitants would not be able to see this moon until they travel to a location where the moon is visible.

Comment: L2 is not always in shade.   Earth's not large enough to completely block the Sun at L2, and JWST is solar-powered, . One of the big reasons that the Webb's is in a halo orbit around L2 is that it puts all the major nearby infrared sources (Sun, and Earth) in  the same direction, so the sunshade can cover them all while still being near enough for good communication, but its halo orbit is set up to [deliberately avoid eclipse by Earth or Moon](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/57727/is-jwst-going-to-be-in-antumbra-at-l2).

Comment: @notovny Thank you, I didn't know that James Webb space telescope's orbit is deliberately avoiding Earth's shadow.